# stats.ttest_ind() vs. "manual" computation of Student's independent t-test: different results

Tags: python, scipy, t-test

I am comparing stats.ttest_ind() vs "manual" computation of the same test, and get different results.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import math
```

stats.ttest_ind() method:

```
#generate data
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'age':np.random.normal(40,5,200).round(),
    'sex':np.random.choice( ['male', 'female'], 200, p=[0.4, 0.6]),
     })

#define groups
men = df.age[df.sex == 'male']
women = df.age[df.sex == 'female']

#run t-test
test_stat, test_p = stats.ttest_ind(men, women)
print(test_stat, test_p)
```

Out:

```
-0.9265613940505325 0.355282312357339
```

Manual method:

```
#mean
men_mean, women_mean = men.mean(), women.mean()
#standard deviation
men_sd, women_sd = men.std(ddof=1), women.std(ddof=1)
#standard error
men_n, women_n = len(men), len(women)
men_se, women_se = men_sd/math.sqrt(men_n), women_sd/math.sqrt(women_n)
#standard error on the difference between men and women
se_diff = math.sqrt(men_se**2.0 + women_se**2.0)
#t-stat
t_stat = (men_mean - women_mean) / se_diff
#degrees of freedom
df = men_n + women_n - 2
#critical value
alpha = 0.05
cv = stats.t.ppf(1.0 - alpha, df)
# p-value
p = (1 - stats.t.cdf(abs(t_stat), df)) * 2
print(t_stat, cv, p)
```

Out:

```
-0.9244538916746341 0.3563753194455255
```

We can see there's a small difference. Why? Maybe because of how stats.ttest_ind() computes degrees of freedom? Any insight much appreciated.

Comment: To get the same t-statistic you need to state that the two groups need not have the same variance, i.e. `ttest_ind(men, women,equal_var=False)`

Comment: and in that case the df-calculation is trickier. see wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works. It is your code from above, with only two rows changed.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import math
#generate data
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'age':np.random.normal(40,5,200).round(),
    'sex':np.random.choice( ['male', 'female'], 200, p=[0.4, 0.6]),
     })

#define groups
men = df.age[df.sex == 'male']
women = df.age[df.sex == 'female']

#run t-test
############################### CHANGED THE ROW BELOW HERE
test_stat, test_p = stats.ttest_ind(men, women,equal_var=False)  
print(test_stat, test_p)
#mean
men_mean, women_mean = men.mean(), women.mean()
#standard deviation
men_sd, women_sd = men.std(ddof=1), women.std(ddof=1)
#standard error
men_n, women_n = len(men), len(women)
men_se, women_se = men_sd/math.sqrt(men_n), women_sd/math.sqrt(women_n)
#standard error on the difference between men and women
se_diff = math.sqrt(men_se**2.0 + women_se**2.0)
#t-stat
t_stat = (men_mean - women_mean) / se_diff
#degrees of freedom
############################### CHANGED THE ROW BELOW HERE
df = (men_sd**2/men_n + women_sd**2/women_n)**2 / ( men_sd**4/men_n**2/(men_n-1)  + women_sd**4/women_n**2/(women_n-1)   )
#critical value
alpha = 0.05
cv = stats.t.ppf(1.0 - alpha, df)
# p-value
p = (1 - stats.t.cdf(abs(t_stat), df)) * 2
print(t_stat, cv, p)
```

and it outputs

```
-0.9244538916746341 0.356441636045986
-0.9244538916746341 1.6530443278019797 0.3564416360459859
```

The reason for the non-consistency in your code is this:

On the line `test_stat, test_p = stats.ttest_ind(men, women)` you accepted the default setting that the t-test is to be computed by the equal-variances assumption. So the computation that `scipy.stats` gives you is a pure equal-variance t-test. That is described in the documentation for [scipy.stats.ttest_ind](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html)

In your own code, you followed the [Welch test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes,_unequal_variances_(sX1_%3E_2sX2_or_sX2_%3E_2sX1)) in general: you computed the estimate of the mean and its standard error for the men and women separately, and computed the t-statistic in that way.

You did deviate from the Welch test in one place: the degrees-of-freedom computation. The degrees of freedom should be approximated with the formula I entered in the code (and linked to above), but you used the computation applicable under [equal-variance assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes,_similar_variances_(1/2_%3C_sX1/sX2_%3C_2)).

IF you want more details on how to compute these statistics, or why they are defined as they are, or why your code is not what you expected it, I suggest you check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ that are more appropriate for statistics questions, in comparison to https://stackoverflow.com/ that is more about the programming. Both those communities are proficient in python as well, so they should be able to help you out perfectly good.

Comment: Many thanks @LudvigH, answer accepted, however can you please say more on two things that are still not clear to me: (1) Since I sampled for the normal distribution, I assumed variance was equal btw samples (although they did not have the same size indeed)? (2) I thought I computed my t-value as in a pooled test, is that not the case?

Comment: I expanded my wording a little bit, but not so much that I let the statistics take more room than the programming. I suggest you implement the equal-variance-assumptions code yourself as well, and see how different it is. If you find that difficult, I suggest you reach out on stats.stackexchange.com with a question. You can ping me there as well.

Comment: Many thanks LudvigH, actually I got it now (indeed the problem was about how I computed degrees of freedom)! And I will remember your suggestion to post more 'statistical' question on stats.stackexchange. Thanks again